# How to prove an assumption given its conclusion from inductive declaration?

Tags: isabelle

Here is a definition of a simple language:

```
theory SimpleLang
  imports Main
begin

type_synonym vname = "string"
datatype exp = BConst bool | IConst int | Let vname exp exp | Var vname | And exp exp

datatype type = BType | IType
type_synonym tenv = "vname ⇒ type option"

inductive typing :: "tenv ⇒ exp ⇒ type ⇒ bool"
  ("(1_/ ⊢/ (_ :/ _))" [50,0,50] 50) where
BConstTyping: "Γ ⊢ BConst c : BType" |
IConstTyping: "Γ ⊢ IConst c : IType" |
LetTyping: "⟦Γ ⊢ init : t1; Γ(var ↦ t1) ⊢ body : t⟧ ⟹ Γ ⊢ Let var init body : t" |
VarTyping: "Γ var = Some t ⟹ Γ ⊢ Var var : t" |
AndTyping: "⟦Γ ⊢ a : BType; Γ ⊢ b : BType⟧ ⟹ Γ ⊢ And a b : BType"

lemma AndTypingRev:
  "Γ ⊢ And a b : BType ⟹ Γ ⊢ a : BType ∧ Γ ⊢ b : BType"

end
```

I defined a typing function for expressions. And I'm trying to prove that if And-expression has a Bool Type then both of its arguments have Bool Type too. It's a reversion of AndTyping rule from the theory.

Could you suggest how to prove this lemma? Could it be proved without Isar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inductive` proves an elimination rule called `typing.cases` for this sort of thing. That allows you to do ‘rule inversion’. The Isar way is to do it like this:

```
lemma AndTypingRev:
  assumes "Γ ⊢ And a b : BType"
  shows   "Γ ⊢ a : BType ∧ Γ ⊢ b : BType"
  using assms by (cases rule: typing.cases) auto
```

Since this is the default rule for case distinctions involving `typing`, you can also just write `by cases auto`. In any case, if you use `cases` for this, you should chain in the assumption involving `typing` with `using`, `from`, etc.

You can also do it without chaining using e.g. `erule`:

```
lemma AndTypingRev:
  "Γ ⊢ And a b : BType ⟹ Γ ⊢ a : BType ∧ Γ ⊢ b : BType"
  by (erule typing.cases) auto
```

There is another way: You can use the `inductive_cases` command to automatically generate a suitable lemma for rule inversion (essentially, it's a specialised version of the `typing.cases` rule):

```
inductive_cases AndTypingRev: "Γ ⊢ And a b : BType"
```

You can make it even more general:

```
inductive_cases AndTypingRev: "Γ ⊢ And a b : t"
```

That gives you an elimination rule `AndTypingRev` that you can use with `erule`, `elim`, or `cases`:

```
?Γ ⊢ And ?a ?b : ?t ⟹
    (?t = BType ⟹ ?Γ ⊢ ?a : BType ⟹ ?Γ ⊢ ?b : BType ⟹ ?P) ⟹
  ?P
```